# my variable resetting after one loop in a for loop, not sure why

Tags: c, for-loop, variable-declaration

i have been trying to make a for loop where at i < j. Variable J takes the length of a string to decide how many loops will happen. This works for the first loop, i have debugged and J does get the value of 3 if i put in a string of 3 characters. The problem is that after the first loop J is reset to the value of 0 and i cant seem to figure out why that is. Can anyone help me? Id still call myself a beginner so any advice on code would be appreciated even if its not about my specific question.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
string prompt = get_string("Give me a word: " );
int j = strlen(prompt);
char word[] = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
        strcat(word, "p");
    }
    
    printf("%s\n", word);

}
```

Comment: With `char word[] = "";` you define an array of only a single element (that element being the string null-terminator character `'\0'`). You can't append to it, any attempt to do so will lead to *undefined behavior*. Set a large enough size of the array and it should start working, like e.g. `char word[j + 1] = "";`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `char word[j + 1] = "";` will not work

Comment: @0___________ You're correct. Too late to edit now, but correct should be `char word[j + 1]; word[0] = '\0';`. To explain for other readers: Variable length arrays can not be initialized in place of definition. Setting the first character to the string terminator allows it to be used as a destination for `strcat`. As for the size, the code adds `j` number of `'p'` characters, plus one for the terminator at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char word\[\] = "";` I belive that it is typo and it should be

```
char word[] = "";
```

You define a `char` array having one element (null terminating character).
When you  `strcat(word, "p");` you invoke **undefined behaviour** as you write outside the array bounds.  Your array has to be big enough to accommodate all the characters and null terminating character.

```
int main(void)
{
    string prompt = get_string("Give me a word: " );
    size_t j = strlen(prompt);
    char word[j + 1];

    word[0] = '\0';

    for (int i = 0; j != 0 && i < j; i++)
    {
        strcat(word, "p");
    }
    
    printf("%s\n", word);

}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/5GPPse96K